# Restricciones para función lineal

Tags: ruby, funciones

Tengo que escribir una función lineal y compararla con patrones para delimitarla y después poder operar con ella.

Ejemplo: `9x+2y+9=0`. Lo que ocurre es que debo restringir la entrada para poder manejar la expresión. Ya hice varias opciones y ya llevo mas de 200 líneas de código, y sigo... ¿Hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo?

```
= gets.chomp.strip.split.join #ingreso de la primera ecuación.

if    a[/\d+x[\+\-]\d+y[\+\-]\d+\=0/] == a
 v_i = a[/\d+x/]
 c_v_i = v_i[/\d+/]
 v_d = a[/[\+\-]\d+y/]
 c_v_d = v_d[/[\+\-]\d+/]
 t_i_p = a[/[\+\-]\d+\W/]
 t_i = t_i_p[/[\+\-]\d+/]
 puts c_v_i
 puts c_v_d
 puts t_i
```

... y eso es solo una opción.